# Задача с десятками и сотнями тысяч

Tags: python

Никак не могу решить эту задачу, даже не знаю с чего начать. Условие такое:

> Дано пятизначное целое число.(Через input) Напишите алгоритм, который возведёт
> количество десятков в степень количества единиц. Затем умножит это
> число на количество сотен. И делит получившееся число на разность
> количества десятков тысяч и количества тысяч

Решения не прошу, просто прошу направить на верный путь.

Comment: ну например можно начать с того, чтобы найти количество десятков и количество единиц. Далее просто брать каждое предложение в задании и выполнять то, что там просится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь можно пойти двумя путями:

---

1. Использовать // и %

Например, чтобы получить из четырёхзначного числа трёхзначную часть, нужно его % на 1000:

```
result = 1234 % 1000  # Остаток от деления
print(result)
```

> 234

Если наоборот, нужен первый разряд, то используется //:

```
result = 4321 // 1000  # Деление нацело
print(result)
```

> 4

---

2. Использовать индексацию строк

```
number = input()  # Число в виде str
print("Единицы:", int(number[-1]))  # Последний символ строки
print("Десятки + 1:", int(number[-2]) + 1)  # Предпоследний символ строки
```

Ввод:

> 12345

Вывод:

> Единицы: 5 
> Десятки + 1: 5

Главное, не забывать приводить символ к типу int.

---

Решение первым способом:

```
number = int(input())
units = number % 10
dozens = number % 100 // 10
hundreds = number % 1000 // 100
thousands = number % 10000 // 1000
doz_of_thous = number // 10000
print((dozens ** units) * hundreds / (doz_of_thous - thousands))
```

Решение вторым способом:

```
number = input()
units = int(number[-1])
dozens = int(number[-2])
hundreds = int(number[-3])
thousands = int(number[-4])
doz_of_thous = int(number[-5])
print((dozens ** units) * hundreds / (doz_of_thous - thousands))
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. Решение не смотрел, но задачу решил с помощью ваших подсказок!

Comment: Рад, что моё решение не пригодилось, я добавил его на всякий случай. Если вопрос закрыт, то один из ответов стоит пометить как решение. Иначе их количество будет расти.

Answer (score 0):

Вычленить всѣ цифры сразу можно такъ:

```
a, b, c, d, e = map(int, input())
```

Остальное тривіально.